# Get values of Dataset in depth 2

Tags: associations

Given the following dataset

```
 ds=Dataset[<|1 -> <|5 -> 1|>, 2 -> <|3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1|>, 
  4 -> <|2 -> 1, 3 -> 10|>,5 -> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1|>|>]
```

I try to replace the value of 'ds' as follows:

```
  ReplacePart[ds, {4, 3} -> 100]
```

But I get a error, how to acces to values in depth 2?

Comment: Assuming `data` is the same as `ds`, this works for me (MMA 11.3 on Win 10). What is your error, and what version are you using?

Comment: Btw, in case you want to access the value in the association under the key 4 (and not the fourth one), use `{Key@4,Key@3}` instead of `{4,3}`

Comment: I restart the notebook, and it is work, but I want to access to the association under key 4 ->key 3 (I am using ver. 11.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReplacePart` interprets numbers the same way as `Part` (`[[…]]`), so `{4,3}` refers to the third element of the fourth element without any regard for the keys of the association.

To interpret the number as a key, use [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html):

```
ReplacePart[ds, {4, 3} -> 100] // Normal
(* <|1 -> <|5 -> 1|>, 2 -> <|3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1|>, 
 4 -> <|2 -> 1, 3 -> 10|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 100|>|> *)

ReplacePart[ds, {Key@4, Key@3} -> 100] // Normal
(* <|1 -> <|5 -> 1|>, 2 -> <|3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1|>, 
 4 -> <|2 -> 1, 3 -> 100|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1|>|> *)
```